# Need Help Getting HTML out of Razor View in ASP.NET Core With Action Result Filter

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0, asp.net-core-middleware

I'm following Steve Smith's article on how to use Filters in ASP.NET Core.  Specifically, I want to get the HTML after it has been processed by the razor view engine.  I've created an action filter and decorated my controller as follows yet I still get an empty html string from the stream.  I think it has something to do with using the Result and not the Context but I'm not sure.  Here is my code:

```
    [AppendToHtmlBodyFilter]
    public IActionResult Videos()
    {
        return View();
    }


    public void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext context)
    {
        Stream originalStream = context.HttpContext.Response.Body;
        using (MemoryStream newStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            context.HttpContext.Response.Body = newStream;
            context.HttpContext.Response.Body = originalStream;
            newStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(newStream);
            var htmlData = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
```